# Closest core sample DBSCAN in scikit

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I would like to find the closest core sample for each datapoint. This way I could represent my data with only core examples (reduce the dataset)

Scikit seems to be only providing an array of all the core samples. The brute force way to compare my datapoint to this array, is to heavy weighted. 
So I would like to get the core samples for one cluster, get the cluster number for a datapoint, and then get the closest core sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DBSCAN is meant to be used this way (data reduction).

But in particular, DBSCAN does *not* compute the *nearest* core point. So it does not have the information you are looking for!

You'll have to do it yourself.

1. Put all core points into a kdtree/balltree
2. Find the nearest neighbor using the index

Scikit-learn provides everything you need already, it should be just a few lines.

Comment: I figured it out.
But to go further on your comment about the fact DBSCAN isn't meant to be used that way. Clustering in general is used to define a pattern and those patterns are defined by the clusters. Isn't it quite logical to approximate datapoints with their closest core sample?

Comment: @Milan I think it depends on your application. If you are just looking to reduce the size of your dataset, using a dimensionality reduction algorithm might be a better choice. This way you could represent more of the variation between samples using  just a few continuous valued features.

Comment: Milan: core points are too unspecific to be a useful pattern. Two points at the exact same coordinates are different patterns with this notion. Also, DBSCAN chose to not assign the noise points to a cluster, now you are doing thr exact opposite by assigning them to a core point, too.

Comment: With Euclidean distance, k-means *is* the statistically best way of doing vector quantization (by the least-squares criterion, k-means tries to find the optimal quantization). If you want to reduce your data set size, look at the theory of what you are doing. I'm not sure if there is a good theoretical argument for using core points here (the nearest local density maximum could work, but core points?).

Comment: You are right. I will look a bit further on the theory around DBSCAN. I'm staying away from k-means because I have no idea on how many clusters my dataset will have.

Comment: For your use case of quantiuation, you do not need "clusters" at all. You choose k based on the compression you want. To reduce the data set to 1000 prototypes, choose k=1000. The worst that can happen is that some prototypes are too similar, but is that a problem?